# Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop Performance and Diagnostics Menu

Tags: performance, diagnostics

I've recently updated my copy of visual studio 2013 to update 5 in the hope I could start using the Performance and diagnostics hub but I get the following message in the options menu.

[image: settings]

There were no error messages from update 5 installation. When I open the application (even a administrator) I don't have the menu item "performance and diagnostics" and I have already  tried to repair the installation.

Before I received the following error message, checking the activity log the error was something about duplicate ID's (Can't share the exact wording as it's not in the log anymore)

[image: error message]

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Completely unrelated, but why not use VS17?

Comment: I use the application at work and only have a license to use 2013

Comment: If the company is larger enough to need the enterprise edition (>250 PCs || >$1m annual revenue) then they should really be providing you with a decent working environment, shouldn't be your job to fix it issues like this.

Comment: VS express is free. You don't need to buy to use it

Comment: Yes i know, i have 2017 for use at home, but the company still requires me to acquire a MSDN license from them before installing it